# pickdate.js parameters and monthPicker

Tags: datepicker

I'm trying to suit well this plugin [pickadate.js v3.3.1](http://amsul.github.io/pickadate.js) but I'm facing some difficulties.

First, I need to restrict selection of only future dates, 3 months from today's date. The docs didn't help me much so tried to do it this way. But it's not working.

Second, can I change this to a MONTH PICKER only? I need this for a Credit Card Expiry date field input.

The documentation isn't very great, But I guess being a new plugin I can use some good help of geeks here.

```
 <script>
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+3; 

        $('#pickdate').pickadate({
                // Escape any “rule” characters with an exclamation mark (!).
                format: 'mmm dd , yyyy',
                formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
                hiddenPrefix: 'prefix__',
                hiddenSuffix: '__suffix',

                min: new Date(),
            max: mm

                //min: new Date(),
            //max: (new Date() + 10)

        })

        $('#picktime').pickatime();
</script>
```

Comment: Use dateMin and dateMax, and pass in dates as arrays, not Date() objects or numeric values (which represent a number of days).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> If dateMax or dateMin is an integer, it represents the relative number
> of days till the min or max date.

I couldn't find any mentioning in the docs of a month picker. Why not use a standard dropdown ()?

What could prove to be of use to you with regards to range, again from the docs, is:

> dateMin and dateMax can be either
>
> 1. an array representing a date ([ yyyy, mm, dd ])